# PHP Error Pagination/Directory Reading

Tags: php, pagination, directory, undefined, offset

So I have an annoying error and my friend isn't online to help me at the moment so why not ask **stackoverflow**!

I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in /home1/username/public_html/foldername/v1/screenshots.php on line 21

What the script does it reads folders and gathers the files in that directory. That part works but however I do get this annoying error I can not figure out.

What I think is happening the script is trying to read images that are not there. Because I use a pagination script that echos the files in that directory. The script works great minus that one error trying to read files that are not there. Is there anyway I can tell the script to say }else{ echo"Nothing Here..."; so to speak? Below is the full code I use.

Edit: (pulled from .txt file)

```
$filearray = array(); if ($fil = opendir("../uploads/")) {
    while (($file = readdir($fil)) !== false) {
if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { $filearray[] = $file;
    }
}
    closedir($fil);
} 
$page = empty($_GET['page']) ? 1 : $_GET['page'];
$num_per_page = 5;
$total_pages = ceil(count($filearray)/$num_per_page);

    for($i = ($page - 1) * $num_per_page; $i < $page * $num_per_page; $i++) {
        echo "<a href=\"http://www.url.com/uploads/".$filearray[$i]."\"><img src=\"http://www.url.com/uploads/".$filearray[$i]."\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" /></a>";
}

$pages = array();
    for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
    $pages[] = "<a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?page=".$i."\">".$i."</a>";
}
echo "<br />Page: ".implode(" ", $pages);
```

Some reason I could not paste the entire code in the form. Any kind of help would be great...

Comment: Please post here the relevant part of your code or the whole file screenshots.php. You can edit your own question.

Comment: Which is line 21? I assume `echo "<a href=\"http://www.steamshots.com/uploads/".$filearray[$i]."\"><img src=\"http://www.steamshots.com/uploads/".$filearray[$i]."\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" /></a>";` as it is the only line with array offsets

Comment: You can always check if array value exists before trying to use it -> `if(isset($filearray[$i])) { echo "<a href=\"http://www.steamshots.com/uploads/".$filearray[$i]."\"><img src=\"http://www.steamshots.com/uploads/".$filearray[$i]."\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" /></a>"; }` This prevents the issue when you have only 6 array values, and so on page 2 you only have only 1 value but are trying to print 5.

Comment: I see you are a new user. Did you know that you should choose one answer as accepted? For this you use the green bird icon next to the number between triangles to the left of the answer. You can also use the up triangle (upvote) on any answer to indicate that it was useful, or the down triangle (downvote) to indicate that it is counterproductive.

Comment: Sean you are my savior buddy that made the error go away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to access an array value that is not in your array. Most likely this is caused on your last page when you don't have enough values - ie. with your error of 7, you are most likely on page 2 and only have 6 `$filearray` values.

A simple fix is to check if the array value exists

```
for($i = ($page - 1) * $num_per_page; $i < $page * $num_per_page; $i++) {
  if(isset($filearray[$i])){
    echo "<a href=\"http://www.url.com/uploads/".$filearray[$i]."\"><img src=\"http://www.url.com/uploads/".$filearray[$i]."\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" /></a>";
  }
}
```

The other way is to check if you have the full amount for the page, and if not set a new max.

```
$max = ( count($filearray) > ($page * $num_per_page) ) ? $page * $num_per_page : count($filearray); // if size of $filearray is larger than the page*numb_per_page set max to page*numb_per_page else set it to the size of $filearray

for($i = ($page - 1) * $num_per_page; $i < $max; $i++) {
    echo "<a href=\"http://www.url.com/uploads/".$filearray[$i]."\"><img src=\"http://www.url.com/uploads/".$filearray[$i]."\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" /></a>";
}
```

Comment: ya it seems that I needed to add the `if(isset($filearray[$i])){` function. I was just over thinking the issue I should of known that was it. isset( seems to solve a lot of those simple errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
```

should be

```
for($i = 0; $i < $total_pages; $i++)
```

In PHP, arrays are indexed starting from 0, so that an array $pages of 7 values will have values $pages[0], $pages[1], ...,  $pages[6], but not $pages[7].

If you start counting from 1 (and supposing $total_pages is 7), then you will try to query $pages[1], $pages[2], ..., $pages[6] (so far so good), $pages[7], which will fire the error because there is no such element in the array.

Comment: Alex some reason your fix did not work Sean fix is what I was looking for. But thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the program that you give in the question the one in screenshots.php? You say the error is on the line 21, but your text has only 20 lines! I can't debug a program that I don't see.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh your logic is correct, but as the OP is doing `for($i = ($page - 1) * $num_per_page; $i < $page * $num_per_page; $i++)` the `($page - 1)` will be the same as your `for($i = 0;`. This method allows the OP to have a link like `?page=1` rather than having to do `?page=0`.

Comment: Yeah I did not give all the code. But that was the main part and this is what fixed it `if(isset($filearray[$i])) { 
  echo "<a href=\"http://www.url.com/uploads/".$filearray[$i]."\"><img src=\"http://www.url.com/uploads/".$filearray[$i]."\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" /></a>"; 
 }` I needed the isset to work for me.

Comment: @Sean Right, I agree.